# Какой запрос использовать в Rest Api?

Tags: php, java, c#, rest

Всем привет. Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли при работе с `Rest Api` всегда использовать только `POST` заголовки? Или это моветон? Согласно `CRUD`, на каждую операцию нужно использовать свой заголовок (`read - GET`,`create - POST` и т.д.) Имеет ли смысл делать такие разделения, или можно всегда использовать только `POST` (а логика будет в теле `JSON`), где сервер при парсинге узнает, что ему сделать, просто вернуть что-либо,  либо произвести что-то и вернуть? Интересно, есть ли какие-то преимущества в скорости, безопасности, при разных заголовках?

Comment: Не кажется ли вам, что все паттерны это не законы, за которые вам отрежут руки, а лишь указания и/или предложения как лучше/качественнее писать код, чтобы был единый стандарт. Я считаю, что, если программа маленькая, допустим, и вам так удобно, вы можете хоть код писать через 20 строчек друг от друга, но, вспоминая обычный русский язык, как вы им пользуетесь, как вам удобно или потому что вам стало так удобно?

Answer (score 2):

Методология `REST` предполагает, что каждый `request` будет выполнять свою функцию. Соответственно,

- `GET` - для получения объекта
- `POST` - для создания объекта
- `PUT` - для апдейта объекта
- `DELETE` - для удаления объекта.

Единственное, что можно отметить - `PUT` и `POST` часто объединяют, так как по факту он выполняет одну функцию.

Для справки, нет четкого обозначения что такое `REST`. Есть правила, и чем больше правил Вы поддерживаете в своем приложении, тем большо оно `REST`. Так же, зачем усложнять себе жизнь и читаемость кода? Подумайте о своих коллегах, которые будут разбираться в вашем коде.

Comment: Один из примеров,почему не хотим GET использовать. Не хотим давать возможность просмотра того же тела JSON, так как зная конечную точку API  не составит труда в обычном браузере увидеть что то ,что не желательно видеть.

Comment: @user321474 Значит, это проблема секьюрности. Если все эндпоинты прописаны правильно, с доступами, ролями, и конкретными юзерами - тогда ни у кого не будет доступа к этому JSON.

Comment: Доступы и роли? Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать? Я так понимаю можно например заголовки типа Authorization еще слать. Проблема в том, что как сделать некий токен клиента,например мобильное приложение, что ему можно слать запросы и получать ответ?

Comment: @user321474 Если используете `Spring`, тогда там есть целый модуль `Spring Security`. Так же советую для каждой авторизации создавать уникальный токен, наверное, на уровне конструктора. Тема очень обширная, с ней мало работал, но прятать `GET` точно не то что нужно делать.